# Calculating Specificity from Weka output

Tags: weka, sensitivity-specificity

In short I need to know or calculate the `sensitivity` and `specificity` from `Weka 3.8.4` output.

## Update

I figured it out. I was confused by the confusion matrix labels. The problem I'm working on has a 'yes' class and a 'no' class. It took me ages to realize that **the 'no' class is the positive class** in the confusion matrix. Once I realized this I was eventually able to work things out.

I was also making mistakes because the `Weka` confusion matrix is a different orientation to the ones I was using as reference from other websites.

## Original post:

Unfortunately I'm weak at math and am confused. I expect this will be evident in my question, which I'm finding hard to word. I find it difficult to understand equations which perform multiple actions in a single step, so I've had to make my equations step-by-step and would really appreciate the same in any answer.

For my data: `True Positives` = 228 and `True Negatives` = 104, total instances = 332

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   <-- classified as
 221   7 |   a = no
   7  97 |   b = yes
```

I am happy to report that I am not confused by the confusion matrix.

## Sensitivity

I have read that `sensitivity` is the same as `Recall` and the same as `TP Rate` so I know I don't need to calculate `sensitivity` explicitly as `Recall` and `TP Rate` appear in the Weka output.

However I am confused by Weka's three lines of output in the `Detailed Accuracy by Class` (below).  I can sort of see why there are three `sensitivities`: sensitivity to *yes*, sensitivity to *no*, and a weighted average which I don't yet understand the meaning of. I have worked out for myself that it's calculated as
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
Weighted Avg Sensitvity &=&\frac{TP + TN}{TotalInstances}\\
&=&\frac{221 + 97}{332}\\
&=&\frac{318}{332}\\
&=&0.958
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

However I'm confused as to what it actually *means*. Is the `Weighted Avg TP Rate` **the** `sensitivity` or is `TP Rate for *yes*` **the** `sensitivity`? My understanding of `sensitivity` is that it is all the instances that really are `yes` so I expect **the** `sensitivity` to be `TP Rate for *yes*`.

## Specificity

I have done some background reading (see below) and I have the impression, possibly incorrectly, that there can be one only `specificity` in total. I understand `specificity` to mean *correct identification of **no***. Therefore I cannot see why there would be three lots of `specificity`: one for *no*, one for *yes*, and a weighted average. As with `sensitivity` I currently have no idea what the meaning of a weighted average specificity would be. And trying to think what `specificity for yes` means is making my head spin.

I understand `specificity` to be calculated as follows:
$$
\frac{TrueNeg}{TrueNeg + FalsePos} = \frac{228}{228 + 7} = \frac{228}{235} = 0.970
$$

What I really don't understand is, whether there should also be a `specificity` for the other two lines of output in `Detailed Accuracy By Class` and, if so, what those `specificity` figures mean.

```
=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.969    0.067    0.969      0.969    0.969      0.902    0.989     0.995     no
                 0.933    0.031    0.933      0.933    0.933      0.902    0.989     0.978     yes
Weighted Avg.    0.958    0.056    0.958      0.958    0.958      0.902    0.989     0.990     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   <-- classified as
 221   7 |   a = no
   7  97 |   b = yes
```

I have read these three excellent explanations:

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specificity_(statistics))
2. [Classeval](https://classeval.wordpress.com/introduction/basic-evaluation-measures/) - this guide is brilliant
3. [Lalkhen and McCluskey](https://academic.oup.com/bjaed/article/8/6/221/406440)

but I'm still unsure whether I need to calculate `specificity` three times. If so, what would those equations be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has two classes: one called `yes` the other called `no`.
However `Weka` does not apply semantics to the labels, they may as well be `tigers` and `lions`.

`Weka` labels the majority class (the bigger class) as the `positive class` and the minority (smaller) class as the `negative class`.

In this situation, the 'no' class was the larger hence it is the `positive class`

Once you understand that, then you can label the confusion matrix cells correctly:

```
TP | FN
-------
FP | TN
```

`Weka`'s confusion matrix is a different orientation to the one currently on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

Now you can do the calculations correctly.